# Add field within loop - Twig - OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel, twig, octobercms

I am trying to loop through records and total up the price values.

Model: `Certfication`
Field: `price`

My loop looks like this:

```
 {% set price = 0 %}
 {% for item in certifications %}
   {% set price = item.price.count %}
 {% endfor %}
```

and then i would use {{ price }} to display the total

Can someone shed some light on why this isnt working?

Answer (score 0):

I put an answer for code visibility, but first I see a mistake :

```
{% set price = item.price.count %}
```

should be (why `.count` ?) :

```
{% set price = price + item.price %}
```

Or you can use sum in your controller :

```
$total = DB::table('certifications')->sum('price');
```

Comment: Hi Vincent, i have updated the origiinal post to show that there needs to be an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `set initial variables outside of the loop` and just again `use that same variable again` to get its old value.

so you can keep on adding a new sums to an old variable.

```
{% set price = 0 %}
{% for item in certifications %}
   {% set price = price + item.price.count %}
{% endfor %}

Total: {{price}}
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Hi Hardik,

Your answer is not returning a value?

Comment: can you check the `item.price.count` variable is having data, by printing it in loop `{{item.price.count}}`

Comment: means you are asking or telling :) .. if you are asking then we are stroing value in price so at last we print `{{price}}` variable

Comment: when i print in loop, {{item.price.count}} it returns 0

Comment: can you share your `Certfication` table schema and its relations